# Bash completion works, but I can't figure out why. Seems not be configured the usual way

Tags: bash

I just installed a tested raspberry pi debian image on my rpi3 (https://raspi.debian.net/tested-images/ arm64 image).

When I log into the system via ssh as root, the bash completion seems to work out of the box. So far, so good. But I can't figure out why it is working.

I looked at the typical places:

**less ~/.bashrc**

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# Note: PS1 and umask are already set in /etc/profile. You should not
# need this unless you want different defaults for root.
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\h:\w\$ '
# umask 022

# You may uncomment the following lines if you want `ls' to be colorized:
# export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
# eval "$(dircolors)"
# alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
# alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
# alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
#
# Some more alias to avoid making mistakes:
# alias rm='rm -i'
# alias cp='cp -i'
# alias mv='mv -i'
```

**less ~/.profile**

```
if [ "$BASH" ]; then\
          if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then\
            . ~/.bashrc\
          fi\
        fi
```

**less /etc/profile**

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
        # and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).
        
        if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
          PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
        else
          PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
        fi
        export PATH
        
        if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
          if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
            # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
            # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
            if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
              . /etc/bash.bashrc
            fi
          else
            if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
              PS1='# '
            else
              PS1='$ '
            fi
          fi
        fi
        
        if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
          for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
            if [ -r $i ]; then
              . $i
            fi
          done
          unset i
        fi
```

**/etc/bash/bash.bashrc** (only excerpt)

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
#fi
```

**/etc/profile.d**

```
empty
```

kernel 5.10.0 arm64
bash 5.1.4

Questions:

1. Where is the bash-completion configured?
2. Is it maybe enough just to install the bash-completion package in this bash version?

Comment: Welcome, `bash-completion` is not installed? Does `dpkg -l | grep bash-completion` shows it?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. I installed `bash-completion`afterwards actually. `dpkg -l  grep bash-completion` indeed shows now that its installed.
I purged `bash-completion` again and I can still do something like that:

`# ls [TAB][TAB]`   
`test1 test2 test3`

Comment: @superurmel That's just standard "list the files in the directory" completion, which works out of the box with Bash. The bash-completion package enables command-specific completions that depend which command you're running. Those may not be enabled yet.

Comment: @NickMatteo that's if you leave a space after the command, if not it returns the list of matching commands.

Comment: Does `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` file exist?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity: It existed after I installed it, yes. I mixed it up then with what @Nick Matteo said. It was the out-of-the-box bash completion (list files in the directory). I also got confused when the `apt`-command did not autocomplete. So sorry for mixing that up. It's solved for me then. I appreciate your comments.

Comment: @superurmel no worries!